# STM32f746G-disco, SD card, f_open returns FR_NO_FILESYSTEM

Tags: httpclient, lwip, stm32f4, fatfs

I have an application which consists of 2 threads and runs on the STM32f746G-discovery board. One thread is implementing an http client (which just gets a file from a server) and the other thread writes a file in the sd card. When i run the threads seperately they work fine, however when I run them at the same time the f_open function (FatFS) returns FR_NO_FILESYSTEM.

It turns out that that is probably caused by the lwIP stack initialization function of the first thread.
I would be glad if anyone had any idea.

Thank you.