# FR_NO_FILESYSTEM error fopen FATFS SPI STM32F103C8 with SanDisk SD Card 1GB

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, spi, fatfs

I work with STM32F103C8T6 and add FATFS and SPI in project. I test project with 8 GB SanDisk microSD but I have FR_NO_FILESYSTEM in f_open function. I change MicroSD and test with 1 GB SanDisk microSD and have this error again. I format SD card but the problem could not be solved. My error is in:
f_open func -> Find_Volume func

```c
if (fs->fsize < (szbfat + (SS(fs) - 1)) / SS(fs))   /* (BPB_FATSz must not be less than needed) */
  return FR_NO_FILESYSTEM;
```

I get help from below sites:

- https://controllerstech.com/sd-card-using-spi-in-stm32/
- https://www.micropeta.com/video29
- https://github.com/eziya/STM32_SPI_SDCARD
- [STM32f746G-disco, SD card, f_open returns FR_NO_FILESYSTEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131477/stm32f746g-disco-sd-card-f-open-returns-fr-no-filesystem)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.